# Проблема с loading во вложеных страницах в Next.js

Tags: nextjs, loading

Всем привет. Сталкивался ли кто с такой проблемой в Next? Суть в том, что есть страница, например, users. И есть вложенные страницы, по этому же [маршруту](https://skrinshoter.ru/sNIah1tDWvi?a) Проблема в том, что когда переходишь на страницу конкретного юзера, сначала грузиться loading родительской страницы, а потом конкретного пользователя. Подскажите как это можно пофиксить? Нужно чтобы грузился сразу пользовательский loading, без родительского.